# Accessing VB functions such as (DateAdd, DateDiff) in a C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am converting a lot of VB.NET code over to C# and there are a lot of VB functions that C# doesn't have such as DateAdd and DateDiff. Can someone tell me the libraries I would have to reference in order to have access to these functions in my C# code if it is even possible. I already tried adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic and it doesn't work.

Time is a factor here which is the only reason I am looking into doing things this way. I want to leave the code in place as much as possible.

Comment: They aren't called DateDiff/DateAdd, etc, but you can take the difference between two `DateTime` objects. Likewise you can add a `Timespan` to a `DateTime`...

Comment: The function I am converting passes params to DateAdd() such as... Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Quarter, Date.MinValue, etc.. I don't have time to figure it out and risk breaking something.

Comment: @JTunney - if you don't have time and can't risk breaking something, why are you porting it in the first place? There's a reason these functions aren't easily accessible: they should be replaced. Also, are you aware you can use C# and VB.Net code in the same program as long as they are in separate Projects/DLLs? You can write new code in C# and reference old code in VB.Net

Answer (score 2):

Opps it actually is in Microsoft.VisualBasic.

You have to access it like this:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd()
```

Comment: This is a smart approach - 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' is a valid, time-tested .NET assembly and you are guaranteed the same behavior as when used from VB.